# when i try to migrate in laravel there is an error "value too long for type character varying(191)"

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

When i try to run php artisan migrate i get the following error :

```
SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 7 ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(191) (SQL: insert into "users" ("name", "email", "email_verified_at", "password", "remember_token", "created_at", "updated_at") values (Admin, eyJpdiI6IlFJUjFsdm9yenlhaEtsangwVG5cL2tRPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IlBJaThTeDNWR3RheVRrcGpLMU9ZZjRmT1J6OVoxcTUzN0tsV0ZZUkdhcG89IiwibWFjIjoiNzc3Y2FhMjNmYjRiMDRhZWYwYWVjY2E5NTFjNDAwYjEyYjAyNTZkZDhhN2UzZGU4ZmYyN2Q1YTA1MTZjN2M2ZSJ9, ?, $2y$10$n3jPdNmqVWhvYtSzAtLBXO/6s693hu06OGMf.kRZD0MaIlEOBcGpS, ?, 2019-12-16 01:23:48, 2019-12-16 01:23:48) returning "id")
```

i honestly dont know what to do. I use pgsql for my database.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to insert a key into an email field in your migrations and it fails with that.

Comment: You are inserting something else in `email` field.Something encrypted/hased data which is too long for column.

Comment: yes because it has to be encrypted. i use Crypt::encryptString to encrypt the email. i can see that it is too long, so how do i make it so that its not

Comment: Then  you have in increase the length of `email` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well its most likely because of `email` field

the length of email column is 191 character and you trying to put more than 191 characters in it you can fix it by providing second argument to string method

`$table->string('email', 300);`

Comment: where do i do this?

Comment: it's usually in `database/migrations/create_users_table.php`

Comment: after that you need to run `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` to remake your database and apply changes

Answer (score 0):

> change the type of column from string to text.